# Meaning of Friedrich Nietzsche's famous quote

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the second sentence in the following paragraph mean that "success and failure" are answers to the attempts to find out something? If so, does that mean that after a thinker does something as experiments and questions, the thinker will get answers to these experiments and questions?

> A thinker sees his own actions as experiments and questions — as
> attempts to find out something. Success and failure are for him
> answers above all.
> —Friedrich Nietzsche, The Gay Science

Comment: I think it would mean the same thing in your language. It's pretty straighforward.

Comment: I would call this "a famous quote of Friedrich Nietzsche's". "Friedrich Nietzsche's famous quote" suggests that this is the only famous quote by him (or the most famous, at least).

Answer (score 4):

> Does the second sentence in the following paragraph mean that "success and failure" are answers to the attempts to find out something?

Yes. Nietzsche is saying that a person who is a true thinker will treat both their successes and failures as answers to the deeper questions in life, and therefore as good things overall, rather than simply good or bad depending on their effects.

> If so, does that mean that after a thinker does something as experiments and questions, the thinker will get answers to these experiments and questions?

Not necessarily. The thinker's actions, etc, are *attempts* to discover things. The attempts may or may not be fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

basically it means that no matter the success or failure of the experiment.
The thinker will get to a result eventually despite the positivity or negativity of the outcome,
existence of a result matters not the color of it...

> Example: the rabbit always comes out of the hat no matter female or
> male

to be so easy to say it...

it means what motivates the thinker to think more is the possibility of existence of a result not the nature of it... (here nature means true or false, Yes or NO, Positive or Negative)

Comment: Can you edit that to clarify more? At the moment it is hard to see what point you are emphasising.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand what the quote is trying to say. My understanding is "Success and failure are just mere results of the questions or experiments, and the true thinker will not get frustrated by the result and keep trying." However, still as a non native English speaker, it's hard to understand why it implies "no matter what the result is".